# Image Asset Studio how to edit or remove images for action bar

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an android project that has a theme for the action bar to set title and icon , also seem to be using app compat . I would like to edit the icons in the action bar and apparently I can only do this through the Image Asset Studio. How can edit , do I have to edit in asset image studio because if that is the case when I right click on the res folder > new I only see the option for new image asset not edit image asset. I would like to edit image asset not add a new one ???

Answer (score 0):

to edit existing icons or other images you need to open them in external program like `Photoshop`/`Illustrator` or `Gimp`.

I'm pretty sure that Android Studio don't have an internal image editor, you can just resize icons to launcher, notification and similar sizes.

Here you would find a useful tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjeWHbsAMlU

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks guys . What I am actually saying is that I can see the images when I run the app but I cant see them in the source file so I am assuming its something to do with image asset studio.

Comment: no, your files are in `app -> src -> res` (check in manager on the left). Double-click  would open the file